# What shapes fit evenly inside a Hexagon

Tags: geometry

So I'm designing a board game that uses a number of adjacent hexagonal boards. These boards need to be divided up into spaces (tiles) that players move through.

I've been playing with using Hexagons inside the board but this leaves you with 6 partial tiles. Are there any recommendations for what shapes would fit into this space.